# Creating releases on Github when the source does not change

Tags: github

I have a case where a repo represents packaging build source for another project. Initially, I tagged releases to match the foreign repo that I would consume when generating packaging. If my packaging source needed to change, I would simply create commits representing those.

When my repo does not change, yet a new release is available in the foreign repo I want to package, I would simply create a new tag (equivalent to the foreign repo) and generate a new release. However, my release tab looked odd when my source was unchanged when creating a new release.

What is a better procedure for creating a new release in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, the source repo has a `CHANGELOG.md` file which you would modify/update in order to mention the new version of the foreign package repo.
(Note: you have [other general files](https://github.com/blog/2380-new-community-tools) as well)

That way, your tag on your repo does include a (minimal) change and reference a new release which includes the foreign repo one.